# Black screen when using RX 470, but works fine with integrated graphics?

Tags: windows, drivers, display, graphics-card, amd-graphics-card

I have been facing a persistent issue with my Dell Optiplex 9020 system equipped with an RX 470 graphics card. The problem started a month ago, where the monitor displays a black screen when connected to the graphics card using a DVI cable. The monitor is working correctly as it functions well with another system. However, when using the integrated graphics, the system works without any issues.
Moreover, remote display access using Google Remote Desktop shows that the computer can be seen functioning correctly.

Troubleshooting steps I have already attempted:

- Tested the monitor with another system, and it works flawlessly.
- Confirmed that the monitor and PC are powered on and functioning properly.
- Replaced the cables connecting the monitor and graphics card, but the problem persists.
- Updated the BIOS and reinstalled the graphics drivers, which resolved the issue temporarily. However, the problem returned after shutting down the system.

System Details:

- Dell Optiplex 9020
- Graphics Card: RX 470

The issue has been ongoing for a month, and I have been using this setup without any problems for over a year before this occurred.

I would appreciate any guidance or suggestions on how to resolve this perplexing issue. Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: The 470 is an older card and that might be the source of the problem  - Not sure how to confirm that's the issue but if integrated graphics works and it doesn't,  but testing the video card on another PC might be a useful data point.  I'd also try a different *output* - I've a card where one output dosen't work and the rest do

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply! Yeah i probably should, but I don't have another system to test it on, will take it to a shop someday. Thing is, sometimes it does work fine, until l restart the system, at which point it goes blank again.

Comment: It's probably not this, but maybe try disabling fast startup in the power settings? Fast startup basically turns your shut down procedure into a semi permanent hibernation of sorts. Disabling it ensures your machine actually shuts down / starts up probably in the real sense,